# How to explain the use of stress to emphasize agreement

Tags: emphasis, stress

In a discussion with someone whose first language is not English, the phrase "that *is* fun" came up, with the stress applied to emphasize agreement. This was taken as an insult; he thought the stress on 'is' was used in a corrective manner (thus implying that he didn't know it was fun), rather than how it was meant. How can I explain this usage to him? It's a part of English that I take for granted, so I don't know any words for it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking how ***sarcasm*** works

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I think you're being too hasty. There was no sarcasm implied; the OP is asking how the use of emphasis works to call attention to agreement. The person thought his English was being corrected. He was offended. It's a fair question.

Comment: @medica: Maybe OP's specific context isn't a "sarcastic" usage. But I still think it ***is*** Off Topic to ask how placing audible stress on a copula conveys "emphasis".

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Why?

Comment: @medica: I'm not exactly a polyglot, but it seems to me most likely *all* languages support the idea of using (audible) stress to convey (semantic) emphasis. And I really can't see why ELU should be concerning itself with a possible distinction between ***is*** conveying either emphatic *refutation* or emphatic *agreement*. In fact, the only reason I can think of for it being asked at all is because OP is thinking of French ***Si!*** (which so far as I know only emphasises refutation, not agreement).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I am still interested in reading an answer and will hold out hope that one will be forthcoming.

Comment: Isn't it the case that the emphasis on *is* to mean agreement must follow some statement expressing the opinion with which you are agreeing? Because that is the case the person can hardly believe you are disagreeing by repeating their sentiment.

Comment: Corrective of what, xolroc? What had your friend just said, which he thought you were correcting with your reply?

Comment: I find the conversation fascinating! But it is still off topic, for it is not about a semantic or syntactic distinction, but about a subjective emotional perception that we cannot even perceive directly let alone analyze. All we will ever know for sure is that the OP emphasized ***is*** for one purpose, and and the non-native listener interpreted it as another purpose. People who have been married for decades spend hours with trained counselors to unravel the idiosyncrasies of emphatic tone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of intonation to imply meaning is not as simple as just *emphasis*. The listener's opinion plays a large part in the interpretation of this kind of intonation.

---

> Example 1:
>
> > You: That be fun.
> >     Me: That *is* fun.
>
> In this context, the emphasis implies a **grammatical correction**.

---

> Example 2:
>
> > You: That isn't fun.
> >     Me: That *is* fun.
>
> In this context, the emphasis implies a **statement correction**.

---

> Example 3:
>
> > You: That is fun.
> >     Me: That *is* fun.
>
> In this context, the emphasis implies an **agreement**.

---

> Example 4:
>
> > You: [no statement about the level of fun]
> >     Me: That *is* fun.
>
> Even to a native speaker, the emphasis here is **ambiguous**, though it is unlikely (impossible?) that it is a grammatical correction. The listener's interpretation of the emphasis is subjective at this point, depending on their assumption about the speaker's assumption of the listener's stance. This is influenced by countless things and to be an expert in it would be to have extremely well-tuned intuition.

---

If the listener's opinion was previously stated, you may explain to your peer the intended meaning. If the stance was not previously stated, I would suggest avoiding emphasis with a person that is not comfortable with subtleties of intonation.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I needed. The stance that was intended was that of agreement, your third one here. I didn't realize that this sort of emphasis was unusual to English, hence why I didn't think anything of using it in the conversation that prompted this question.

Answer (score 0):

"That *is* fun" in agreement and "That *is* fun" in contradiction of someone claiming something is not fun would actually have different intonations in my experience of spoken english. The contradictory one would would have a higher and more emphasised "is".